# PHP Send query string with button

Tags: php, html, get

I have a form for searching products which will be visible in each page. When the search button is clicked it will redirect to a *search.php* page. I want to send a query string (parameter) with the content of the search text box when the button is clicked. The code for the form is simple, but here it is:

```
<form method="post" action="search.php">
    <input type="text" id="txtSearch" name="txtSearch" class="searchInput" value="" />
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" value="Search" ?>'" />
</form>
```

I want that when clicked this will redirect to search.php?q=*txtSearch*. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use :

```
<form method="get" action="search.php">
    <input type="text" id="txtSearch" name="q" class="searchInput" value="" />
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

Change "POST" to "GET" on the form element and change the input name parameter to "q".

Answer (score 1):

```
<form method="post" action="search.php?q=txtSearch">
    <input type="text" id="txtSearch" name="txtSearch" class="searchInput" value="" />
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

This way submitting the form you'll be redirect to `search.php?q=txtSearch` and from php you can get the $_POST variable so

`$_POST['txtSearch']`
`$_POST['btnSubmit']`

Answer (score 0):

Just use GET instead of POST

```
<form method="get" action="search.php">
```

The name of the fields will be the name of the querystring variable. Like this:

```
?input_name=input_value
```